# Що означають слова "кобіта" та "трафив шлях" в пісні "Павук" українського виконавця Дзідзьо?

Tags: етимологія, значення-слів, діалекти, ненормативна-лексика

В пісні [Dzidzo (Дзідзьо) ft. VovaZilVova - Павук](http://www.pisni.org.ua/songs/6282178.html) є такі слова:

> Бодя був чорний і білий, Бодя не був дебілом.
>       Але його кобіта вважала не так.
>       І врешті не стерпіла і щось червоне підлила -
>       І Бодьку отруїла і Бодьку трафив шлях.

Що означають слова *кобіта* та *трафив шлях* і що це за діалект?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*Трафив шляг* походить від німецького *schlag treffen* - "інсульт настав", але зазвичай вживається як загальне прокляття, або просто велике нещастя, як у цій пісні.

*Кобіта* з польської *жінка*.

Обидва вирази доволі розповсюджені на Західній Україні.

Comment: У вас написано "шляг", в тексті пісні - "шлях", проте я зустрічав і третє написання - "шляк". Який варіант правильний?

Comment: Я не знаю, чи існує академічний спосіб запису цього запозичення. "шляґ" було б найближче до оригіналу, звідки зрозуміло походження "шляк". У мене немає кваліфікації вважати, що "шлях" - це правильно чи неправильно.

Comment: А щодо діалекту, чи є якась приналежність цих виразів? Дзідзьо має [Надсянський говір](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%80).

Comment: @sashaeve, як носій одного із варіантів галицького діалекту, можу сказати що найпоширеніший локальний варіант - це `шляк`.

Answer (score 17):

Доповнення до [відповіді Sassa NF](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/398/4) — приклади:

- «Кобіта»:

  - Ну, відгуляли ми ті запоїни, я на сьомому небі — така чарівна **кобіта** — моя, винайняв кімнату на краю міста, привезли нас туди дружечки, побажали щасливої солодкої ночі… *<sub>//М. Братан «Голодна кров» (2008)</sub>*
- «Шляг/шляк трафити» — використовують і так, і так. «Шляг» використав М. Коцюбинський:

  - Блакитне небо замазалось сірим, море гір потемніло, полонина погасла, і отара овець повзе по ній, як сірий лишай. Холодний вітер розправля крила і б’є ними у груди попід кептар. Так трудно дихать, що хочеться обернутись до нього спиною. Хай б’є… Тонко заводить вориння, як муха в тенетах, скиглить біль нестерпучий, плаче самотній сум… Дз-з… дзи-и… Невгавуче, безперестанку. Висотує жили і крає ножем по серці. Хтів би не слухать, але не можна, хтів би втекти — та де? Гісь-гісь!.. А ти куди?.. Шляг би ті трафив! Бир-бир!.. Мурко!.. Але Мурко вже навертає. Обганяє вівцю, вітер настовбурчив на ньому шерсть, а він зловив вже зубами за карк вівцю і кинув в отару. Дз-з-и и… Дз-зі-і-і… Так зуби болять одноманітним і нестерпучим болем. Зціпив би зуби й замовк. Боли. Дзичи, пек ті та цур! Що воно плаче? Відай, се "той", бодай скаменів!.. Отак, здається, впав би на землю, безсилий, затулив вуха руками та би заплакав… Бо вже не годен… Дз-з-и-и… Дзі-у-у!.. Йой!.. *<sub>//М. Коцюбинський «Тіні забутих предків» (1911)</sub>*

  Зате сучасні автори майже завжди пишуть «шляк»:

  - Компаньйони засвічувалися, мов каганці, а мене шляк трафляв. *<sub>//Б. Бойчук «Життя з Алісою поза дзеркалом» (2004)</sub>*
  - Станімір не знав, що на те відповісти, його вже «шляк трафляв» од такої гутірки, та, опанувавши себе, він різко підвищив голос: «Я прийшов до вас не торгуватися!» *<sub>//В. Шкляр «Маруся» (2004)</sub>*
  - Або шахраї, або шпекулянти, шляк би їх трафив!  *<sub>//В. Шкляр «Залишенець. Чорний ворон» (2009)</sub>*

  Маю сумніви, що хтось пише «шлях трафити» — бо тоді просто виходить омонімія зі словом «[шлях](http://sum.in.ua/s/shljakh)». Та й не факт, що в наведеній Вами пісні співають «шлях» — скоріше за все, це помилка транскрипції (одрук, можливо, непомічений результат автокорекції або просто записувала неграмотна людина чи людина, що не знала цього виразу і підібрала найближче схоже слово), що поширилася мережею. Якщо послухати оригінал, то там майже явно «шляк».

Answer (score 0):

Я живу на Львівщині. І це наша розмовна мова. Кобіта, то жінка. "Маєш файну кобіту, тє не злостит."   Або товариша його кобіта затягнула в неділю в діточе кафе, без алкоголю,  він сі висловив і прислав фотографію: " не го шляк трафит"

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Ця відповідь, на жаль, не містить нічого, що не було б зазначено у наявних відповідях. Будь ласка, завжди перевіряйте наявні відповіді перед тим, як написати свою.